# GROUP_CONCAT with condition

Tags: mysql, group-concat

In the following example, I use group-concat to concatenate car and new_color.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( car, ' - ' , new_color) ORDER BY car SEPARATOR '; ') AS car_color
```

RESULT:

```
Fiat -;
Ford - red;
BMW - blue;
```

How to do the '-' (separating the car from new_color) be added only if new_color have a value.

In my example, the desired result is:

```
Fiat ;
Ford - red;
BMW - blue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat_ws`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' - ', car, case when trim(new_color) = '' then null else newcolor end) ORDER BY car SEPARATOR '; ') AS car_color
```

Like @[**Matteo Tassinari**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443080/matteo-tassinari) said, `NULLIF(TRIM(new_color), '')` will be more simple in mysql.

Comment: That will work **only** if `new_color` is `NULL`, an empty string would still be concatenated.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Good catch, I'm trying to fix it when you comment here. Please check it again.

Comment: Thanks Forward and Matteo

Comment: Now it'll work :) you could simplify that `CASE` statement with `NULLIF(TRIM(new_color), '')`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

Comment: Thanks again Matteo Tassinari

Comment: With this query, Concat_WS will run for every records and will have effect on speed, its better to use CASE statement before Concat function, see my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CASE new_color WHEN NULL THEN car WHEN '' THEN car
                    ELSE CONCAT(car, ' - ' , new_color) END
                    ORDER BY car SEPARATOR '; ') AS car_color
FROM car_table
```